# Is it possible to use Solr with SSL and CA-Signed Certs

Tags: security, ssl, solr, lucene, jetty

I'd like to use SSL with my Solr instance (in the cloud).
The instructions here speak only to using a self-signed cert https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Enabling+SSL#EnablingSSL-CreateaSolrCloudcollectionusingbin/solr

But I'd rather not distribute around a keystore/truststore to each Solr node and my clients too.

Is there a way I can use CA-signed certs with Solr?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your CA cert into .PFX and place it in etc folder and update config as below -

```
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/<certfilename>.pfx
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=PKCS12
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java truststore and keystore files are the same regardless if its self-signed or CA-signed certificates.

Using the instructions from your CA, import the appropriate certificates to the truststore and keystore that Solr will use, and then configure your Solr to point to your new truststore/keystore files (and required passwords to access the certificates).

In other words, follow the instructions you linked, just skip the first step (*Generate a self-signed certificate and a key*), the rest of the instructions are still valid, even with your CA-signed certificates.

Comment: Thanks but if its a CA-signed cert I don't need to import it into a truststore it should be already trusted via the CA.